# A picture proof that sets in the ordered Mostowski model have a least support

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

In Jech's book on the Axiom of Choice he presents in chapter 4.5 the ordered Mostowski model $\mathcal{V}$. One useful fact about this model is that every $x \in \mathcal{V}$ has a least support. The following lemma is used to show this:

> Lemma: If $E_1$ is a support of $x$ and $E_2$ is a support, then $E_1 \cap E_2$ is a support of $x$.

About the proof of this lemma Jech only comments: "the proof is based on the following fact, which can be proved
more easily by drawing a picture than in writing, and thus we leave it to
reader's imagination: Let $E_1$ and $E_2$ be finite subsets of $A$, $E = E_1 \cap E_2$. If $\pi \in G$ is such that $\pi(a) = a$ for each $a \in E$, then we can find a finite number of permutations $\pi_1\rho_1, \dots, \pi_n\rho_n$ such that $\pi_i \in \text{fix}(E_1)$ and $\rho_i \in \text{fix}(E_2)$ for each $i = 1, \dots, n$, and $\pi = \pi_1\rho_1 \dots \pi_n\rho_n$.

What is the proof and picture that Jech is thinking of?

Comment: Side note: does Jech not mean: "If $E_1, E_2$ are supports for $x$, then so is $E_1 \cap E_2$"? Also, in the book he writes $\pi_i\rho_i$ instead of $\pi_1\rho_1$ on two occasions; I have assumed this to be a typo and fixed it in my question.

Comment: @Rob: This is not quite the tag for this. The picture suggestion was more towards "proof by example", rather than a proof without words.

Answer (score 4):

The point is that this is something that once you visualise, is easy to understand how a proof *should* look like, but nevertheless, writing one in full detail is an excruciatingly long and borderline unnecessary torture (which, by the way, is illegal under the Geneva Conventions, so by asking this very question you're risking breaking international law).

Here is the gist. Suppose first that $E_1\cap E_2=\varnothing$, this means that we should be able to write any permutation in our group as a product of permutations from $\DeclareMathOperator{\fix}{fix}\fix(E_1)\cup\fix(E_2)$.

Of course, any permutation that does not require moving anything from $E_1\cup E_2$ is already doing the job, in fact even moving only points from at most one of them is already its own decomposition. So we might as well assume that we move something from each of $E_1$ and $E_2$.

Say that we moved $a\in E_1$ and $b\in E_2$. So why not just assume for a start that $E_1=\{a\}$ and $E_2=\{b\}$? That's simpler. Let me call our permutation $\pi$. And without loss of generality $a<b$.

The more difficult case is that when $a<b<\pi(a)<\pi(b)$, and equivalently when $\pi(b)<a$. And by understanding this one, the simpler case where $a<\pi(a)<b<\pi(b)$ is also understood.

Let $U$ be a large enough interval containing $a,b,\pi(a),\pi(b)$. And now partition $U$ into open intervals: $U_a$ contains $a$, $U_b$ contains the other three points, and $U_c$ is a third intervals which lies between $U_a$ and $U_b$. Note that we use the fact that the rationals are totally disconnected here.

First we move with some $\pi_0$ the interval $U_b$ to $U_c$ and fix $U_a$ pointwise. This is an order isomorphism and it lies in $\fix(\{a\})$. Next move $a$ to $\pi_0(\pi(a))$, and $\pi_0(b)$ to $\pi_0(\pi(b))$. But we can do better, there is some $\pi_1\in\fix(\{b\})$ which will satisfy that $\pi_0^{-1}\circ\pi_1$ acts like $\pi$ on a large enough interval around $a$ and $b$.

Finally, we can correct the necessary values of $\pi_0^{-1}\pi_1\pi_0$ by some permutation moving only things outside that interval.

---

The more complicated your $E_1$ and $E_2$ are, and the more $\pi$ moves them between the different intervals given by the points in each set, the more complicated the above idea becomes. But ultimately, this is something that follows from the fact that partial automorphisms can be extended to automorphisms. So we move them "slowly" and "carefully".

Comment: Maybe I should have said, but the group $G$ is the subgroup of all permutations of $A$ that preserve order ($A$ being ordered as $\mathbb{Q}$).

Comment: Right. But it's the same idea (now we need to move small enough half-closed intervals instead of finitely many points). As I wrote in response to the tag change, this is more of a conceptual "convince yourself" sort of thing.

Comment: I've removed the tag and I agree. I have an argument along the lines you suggest (I think) using a picture, but I was dissatisfied because I feel I might be wrong (e.g. it wouldn't do on a exam I think, and at any rate be hard to jot down). Maybe this is Jech being slightly lazy, but the way I read his remark I was expecting a specific picture more towards the direction of proof without words, although obviously not in the meaning of the tag: you need some words at least surely.

Comment: I will post my solution after the exam if nothing cleaner is posted.

Comment: To be fair, I think it's an unfair question to give to your students in an exam, unless of course you've given the proof in class. As for Jech being lazy, well, he's known for being telegraphic and skimp details. But this sort of argument, in particular, is sometimes just... messy if you just do it in detail. And it's nearly impossible to understand the idea of the proof from reading the details plainly. But once you've "convinced yourself", this is much easier to understand.

Comment: I've edited to reflect the case of the order automorphisms. The reason I was confused is that later on, in Cohen's first model, there's a similar argument with permutations of $\omega$.

Comment: Thanks Asaf. I now see my original idea was wrong: in maneuvering the $a, b$ I forgot that it are the original positions of $a, b$ that should be kept fixed, not any new positions. I think I understand your solution, but to be sure: when you move $U_b$ to $U_c$ where do you leave $U_c$? Just somewhere between $a$ and the left side of the new $U_b$?

Comment: Oh, and I missed that we need that the rationals are totally disconnected. Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: Lastly, could you clarify what you mean by "large enough"? Why do you need it?

Comment: You just compress $U_c\cup U_b$ into $U_c$. And large enough just think about this in the case of the rationals where we have a notion of length.

Comment: Okay, that's fine. But for example you say: "Let $U$ be a large enough interval containing $a$,$b$,$\pi(a)$,$\pi(b)$"; why would not any $U$ containing $a$,$b$,$\pi(a)$,$\pi(b)$ do? I think I'm confused over that. Btw, thanks for your help, it's really appreciated by the set theory noobs ;)